# MySQL Dump Files―library for parsing, modification and writing

Tags: java, mysql, parsing

Preamble: I am not new to programming, but I started just Java a year ago, so my knowledge for it is not too big. My knowledge of MySQL is also not too advanced, I know how to write queries, but I am not an expert in it.

Lately I wrote a little cli Java-Program that reads a *.sql file produced by mysqldump, replaces some Strings and generates a new modified *.sql file. Unfortunately I ran into some Problems with it, so I would like to apply the search and replace only on INSERT statements.

So I am searching for a library with which I could write something like (pseudo-code):

```
parsedsql = SQLParser.parse( <path-to-file );
inserts = parsedsql.getAllStatementsByName( 'insert' );

for( statement s in inserts )
{
    searchAndReplace( parsedsql, statement.valueToInsert );
}
```

In short: Is there an open source library that can take MySQL-Code from a file or a String, generates some kind of statement based object structure I can modify and can also produce a resulting String or file? (The manipulation of the input should be as little as possible, but as much as necessary)

If something like this does not exist, I would appreciate any kind of advise which supports me solving this.

Thanks in ahead!

Comment: well I would to find/manipulate strings of php-serialized objects. Especially strings are difficult, because they include the length of the string which needs to be adjusted after search and replace. Would be much easier to manage this job if I would have the content of the insert separated from the rest of the dump-file.